# Display php array api contents

Tags: php, arrays, api-design

I am working with a API. the link shows in the class like this

> private $apiPath = "http://www.website.com/api/v1/users/username";

now if the username part is tom and i put it in the browser like so.

> private $apiPath = "http://www.website.com/api/v1/users/tom";

it will display all toms stats in text format.

I am trying to figure out how to display it in HTML rendered format
using php so i can display it on my site. I was told its in an array.

so I am assuming using variables i can get it to display what and where I want. I am just really unclear.

I have the class but unsure what to do. do i include it?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the array returned by the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will allow you to grab the username from db and compare

```
function stats(){

    $user_id = $_GET['uid'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $user_id ";
    $result = query($sql);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
    $username = $row->username);

    $url = ('"http://www.website.com/api/v1/users/'.$username);
    $rCURL = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $aData = curl_exec($rCURL);

    curl_close($rCURL);

    $response = json_decode($aData, true);    

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the data that the API is returning, that class would tell me that it is returning JSON which is a [data interchange format](http://www.w3schools.com/json/). You could use PHP's cURL function to get the data from the API and then decode it into a PHP array using [json_decode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then you could do what you like with the data.

For example:

```
$apiUrl = "http://www.website.com/api/v1/users/$username";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$apiURL);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$userArray = json_decode($result, true);
```

If you need to use the class as you need to process the data into the form it does, you will need to include the class and use it.

```
import 'myclass.php';

$userData = new statsProfile('name');
```

Then you can use the other methods of the class as you need.